# Save plain text to RTF file

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, rtf

In a Windows COM application, running on a server, I need to be able to have a method like:

`saveTextToRTF(const wchar_t* content, const char* path);`

It would simply write the text to an RTF file with no formatting. Does WinAPI and/or RTF format make this easy to do without using 3rd-partly libs or writing lots of RTF-specific code? I know MFC controls can do similar things; that's not suitable on the server but maybe they utilise some API calls I can use to do the same thing?

For instance [CRichEditCtrl::StreamOut()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0k0ywek.aspx) does this kind of thing, I can't use that but can I hijack the underlying functionality?

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/librtf/ ?

Comment: No, because I was hoping not to need a 3rd-party lib, it is a bit of a hassle getting a new library approved.

Comment: For *very* plain text, all you need is `{\rtf This is plain text.\par This is plain text.\par This is plain text.\par}` (beware of the few special characters that need escaping).

Comment: The Ubuntu man pages have [a nice description of the bare minimum you need to know to write rtf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man3/RTF::Cookbook.3pm.html).

Comment: Well `CRichEditCtrl` just wraps the underlying [rich edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and uses the [EM_STREAMOUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774304.aspx) message to do the work. You can possibly just create a dummy control and let this do it for you without needing MFC.

Comment: Windowless rich edit is perhaps what you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787609.aspx although since you want no formatting, it's pretty trivial to write your own rtf emitter that will escape the text appropriately

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's fascinating but a little over my head, if you wanted to provide an answer based around it? It looks to me my two choices are to do that, or manually rip an RTF file.

Comment: @RogerRowland I'd b nervous to do that on a windowless server app :)

Comment: @John Nervous or not, it's what you asked - *"I can't use that but can I hijack the underlying functionality?"* I'd be more nervous using the old and badly documented windowless rich edit "feature", which BTW is not properly supported on 64-bit OSes.

Comment: Using an MFC or plain Win32 control in a windowless console server app has to be as dodgy :) By "underlying" I wondered if the RTF->stream functionality was exposed in some API one could safely use.  It seems it partly is, but would not be a great idea - do you have a source to back up your not supported on 64-bit OS comment?

Comment: @John *"...do you have a source..."* - yep, no idea what the current status is though so it may be fixed (not holding breath) - [see the MS connect report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551071/the-6-0a-sdk-is-missing-riched20-lib-for-x64)